# Anaconda Tensorflow Compiler Issue CPU AVX AVX2

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, conda, avx, avx2

I installed Tensorflow via Anaconda, I tried testing if it works using the short program on the website, but I ended up with this error. Is there something wrong, or is it my CPU can't handle it?

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2018-02-22 15:44:55.964179: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
>>>
```

Comment: I still don't understand, do I have to reinstall tensorflow or do I need a GPU in order to use it? I got it to work on Pycharm, but it still has the same error message.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning that it's running slower than it could.